# Why hangfire delayed job getting scheduled multiple times?

Tags: .net, hangfire

**Background :**

1. We are using Hangfire(Hangfire.Core 1.7.32) to schedule delayed
   jobs. As per Hangfire documentation delayed job should get executed
   only once.
2. Hangfire job Scheduling is done through web application.
   we have a process of assigning an order to a delivery agent, if he
   does not accept that order in 4 hours after assignment then that
   order assignment gets expired.
3. For this Order assignment expiration
   we are using hangfire.

**Question:**

In my case **sometimes** **not always** same delayed job getting queued multiple times with very less time difference. And this is not happening on local it only happens on server(dev, qa, UAT).

1. I am not getting why it is not happening on local?
2. What is a cause behind these multiple job entries on server?
3. How we can solve this issue?

**Code:**

```
    public async Task AssignOrder(int ordeid, int agentId)
    {
    //here order assignment and dependent operations happens.
    //after that we are scheduling call to order expiration, means we 
   //are calling Schedule method mentioned below.
    }

public string Schedule(Expression<Action> methodCall, DateTimeOffset enqueAt)
        {
            return BackgroundJob.Schedule(methodCall, enqueAt);
        }
```

Comment: You should first ensure that several dev environments do not schedule their jobs on the same jobserver.
Also you should show the code calling this `Schedule` method. How do you ensure it is not called several times ? (for example if the scheduling is done upon web application startup and you have several application servers in your cluster, you end-up with several schedulings) These considerations would explain why this does not occur on local.

Comment: and also, this may be helpful if you want to dynamically check what has been scheduled :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72407314/1236044

Comment: @jbl Scheduling is done through web application, I have updated the question. We have 2 servers in cluster for QA env.

Comment: @jbl to ensure Schedule method is not called several time we have hangfire worker count 1.  But dev, qa environment has 2 server instances.